# Why does Mathematica change my type style when using the control button to create expressions?

Tags: front-end, formatting

When I am typing in a text line in Mathematica, if I use a control hotkey, such as Ctrl+/ for creating a fraction or Ctrl+6 for a superscript, the item I create is highlighted in a yellow box and the formatting is odd. As an example, in the picture below the letter p looks different on the top and bottom for some reason.
[image: Odd Formatting]

Does anyone know how to fix this? It has been bugging me for weeks and I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Such things happen for the in-line mathematical expressions. In most cases, if you type a text string and need to start an in-line mathematics, you have to press Ctrl+9. Then you see the field with a changed background color (yellow in your case), while the cursor is in, and the letters are in italics. Some combinations like Ctrl+/ , Ctrl+_ or Ctrl+° make it automatically. The way out of it is to always type Ctrl+9 prior to start introducing a mathematical in-line expression.